# Hide tab bar causing incorrect UIView positions

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

In my view controller I have a UIView (drawer view) that sits below the visible screen with just the top poking out (a tab). This tab can be tapped and the UIView will animate up and fill most of the screen. The view is set like so:

```
drawerView = DrawerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - DrawerView.submitTabHeight, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height*0.75))
drawerView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(drawerView)
```

Below is a screenshot of the setup:

[image]

I have to present this view controller from a tab bar controller. I want to hide the tab when the view controller is loaded and I did this by setting `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` in the IB. The problem I have now is that when I push the view controller the drawer view is temporarily out of place. It is higher up than it should be by the height of the tab bar (shown by the dotted line on the screen). It then jumps back to the actual position it should be in. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You have set the bottom constraint for the drawerview?

Comment: no bottom constraint no

Comment: Then what are you doing?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya the frame for the view is set in viewDidLoad

Comment: have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the tabbar before pushing the viewcontroller.

```
if (self.tabBarController) {
        self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }
```